# Get JSON string from within javascript on a html page using shell script

Tags: json, regex, shell, sed, jq

There's valid json in a javascript on a html page that I want to parse with a shell script.
First of all I would like to get the entire json string from `{` to `}` and then I can parse it with `jq` for example.

This is basically how my html looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foobar</title>

  </head>

  <body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/script.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/resources.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    if( foo.foobar.getInstance().isbar() ) 
    {
        foo.bar.Processor.message( {"head":{"url":"anotherfoo;barid=347EDAFA2B136D7825745B0A490DE32"},...});
    }
    else
    {....}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the end  I want to get the ID that's at "barid=...". 
I was playing around trying to use `grep foo.bar.Processor.message` and then `sed` or `cut` but I think there's better ways to do it.
If you could point me in the right direction that'd be great! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is not recommended to use unix command line tools for parsing HTML. But if you know your marker string `foo.bar.Processor.message`, then you may use this `sed + jq` solution:

```
sed -n 's/foo\.bar\.Processor\.message(\([^)]*\).*/\1/p' file.html |
jq -r '.head.url | split(";")[1] | split("=")[1]'
```

```
347EDAFA2B136D7825745B0A490DE32
```

In the absence of `jq`, you may use this `sed + gnu grep` solution:

```
sed -n 's/foo\.bar\.Processor\.message(\([^)]*\).*/\1/p' file.html |
grep -oP ';barid=\K\w+'
```

Answer (score 3):

One option might be to use [pup](/questions/tagged/pup), at least for parsing the HTML:

```
< input.html pup 'script:not(:empty) text{}' |
  grep foo.bar.Processor.message | grep -o '{.*}' |
  jq -r '.head.url
         | split(";")[]
         | select(test("barid="))
         | sub("barid=";"")'
```

With your HTML (adjusted to ensure the JSON in the HTML is valid), this produces:

```
347EDAFA2B136D7825745B0A490DE32
```

Of course there are many caveats.  YMMV.