# Use jq to select specific item from array

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

I have this json string :

```
{
    "head": {
        "url": "foobar;myid=E50DAA932C22739F92BB250C14365440"
    }
}
```

With jq on the shell I get the content of `url` as an array:

```
jq -r '.head.url | split(";")[] '
```

This returns:

```
foobar
myid=E50DAA932C22739F92BB250C14365440
```

My goal is to get the id (E50DA...) after `=` only. I could simply use `[1]` to get the second element and then use a regex to get the part after the `=`.
But the order of elements is not safe and I'm sure there's a better way with jq already that I dont know of. Maybe create a map of the elements and use `myid` as a key to get the value (E50...)?

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to do it with `jq` only? You could further process the output with `grep` and `cut`:

```
jq '.head.url | split(";")[]' | grep '^myid=' | cut -d= -f2
```

---

But alas, it is easily possible by first building an object from the key value pairs and then look up the value for the key in question:

```
.head.url
  | split(";")
  | map(split("=") | { key: .[0], value: .[1] })
  | from_entries
  | .myid
```

equivalent to:

```
.head.url
  | split(";")
  | map(split("=") | { key: .[0], value: .[1] })
  | from_entries["myid"]
```

Or without building an object, simply by selecting the first array item with matching key, then outputting its value:

```
.head.url | split(";")[] | split("=") | select(first == "myid")[1]
```

NB. `x | split(y)` can be expressed as `x/y`, e.g. `.head.url/"@"`.

Comment: No, there's no need to do it entirely in jq. I was just eager to learn more about it. Sure, I can further process it with grep and cut. Thank you !

Comment: @tzippy check my updated answer, I have now provided several jq-only solutions (with and without building a lookup object).

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq`'s `match()` with positive lookbehind to output what's after `myid=`:

```
$ jq -r '.head.url | split(";")[] | match("(?<=myid=).*;"g").string' file
E50DAA932C22739F92BB250C14365440
```

or drop the `split()` and `match()` after `myid=` until the end or `;`:

```
$ jq -r '.head.url | match("(?<=myid=)[^;]*";"g").string' file
E50DAA932C22739F92BB250C14365440
```

Comment: An explicit answer using `select` was already given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947130/get-json-string-from-within-javascript-on-a-html-page-using-shell-script